# Can someone explain why this is giving segmentation fault?

Tags: graph, adjacency-list

Here is the link of my code. If i simple print the list by taking iterators for each row it works but in loop it is giving segmentation fault.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
list<int> *adj = new list<int>[5];
void addEdge(int v,int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}
int main()
{
    addEdge(1,2);
    addEdge(2,3);
    addEdge(3,4);
    addEdge(4,5);
    addEdge(5,2);
    for(int i =1;i<6;i++)
    {
        list<int>::iterator j;
        for(j = adj[i].begin();j!=adj[i].end();++j)
        {
            cout<<*j<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The range of acceptable indices for array available at `adj` are `0..4`, not `1..5`. `C`-like languages tend to use offset-based indices.

The outer `for` loop exceeds that available range of indices. and the program crashes when you refer to `adj[5]` in the inner `for` loop. You are referring to an address on the heap which you do not possess.

In future please try running the program in a debugger like `gcc` or use tools like `valgrind` (it allows you to track memory usage and access).